# How do I smoothly transition fixed-size-div from one container to another on re-render?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

**Abstract**

[Expected transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXhpu.png)

Not exact, but relevant to mine example:

1. State0: assume you have a container1(chessboard with divs for pieces on it) and dead-pieces-view(container2). Positions of container1 and container2 are up to CSS and device/media variables, handled by browser.
2. State1: Piece gets smashed, so it should be moved from the board to the dead-pieces view on the corresponsing placeholder, smoothly.

I have ability to positively identify moving div's with unique ids/keys.

**Other preconditions**:
I'm using React, so I expect smooth transition being done just from the difference of two renders: render(State0) -> render(State1). (Or, at least, with minimal imperative code injections)

Here's my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-pasteur-lr4ku

**What else have I tried**:

1. I tried using react keys and ids to identify the moving div. But it wasn't react problem: moving div with pure js (appendChild) doesn't provide smooth transition either.
2. I tried to use react-pose, because it seems like something that I'd need. But it is limited to grouping ul/li elements only, other animated examples/elements are independent from other page elements (or I didn't research the abilities of framework properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found concept that may work out for me.

**Abstract**:

Whenever div1 changes position to div1', kill div1 immediately, while providing animation for div1' from the last known place using keyframes, 1 iteration.

**Technical**:

React: componentWillUnmount => save current position of element which is uniquely identified

React: componentDidMount => calculate difference, create animation on the fly, setState to re-render with animation.

Unfortunately, requires some global states and other anti-patterns as well, but works.

**Working example**(based on question): https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-hill-ti6bs

Key points:

1. No absolute positioning anywhere
2. I'm able to resize page/browser/viewport, containers get rerendered according to CSS properties
3. Target div successfully moves to the new spot when re-rendered. Able to continue if previous animation didn't finish.

Comment: technically, this is animation of a new element, not transition of an existing one (but it works very nice!)

Comment: Corrected my answer :) In case you refer to question, not answer, then yes, the goal was how it looks, not specifically CSS transition property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- ensure the parent remains the same between re-renders (React would delete/create a new child if the parent is different, so no transition of "existing" child would possible - the parent needs to have persistent key, e.g. `key: idx === parentContainer ? "withBlock" : idx`)
- have some transitionable property (automatic static position is not possible to transition), e.g. `position: absolute` in the styles and modifiable `top`

Then you can modify the transitionable property after each render, e.g.:

```
const Block = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) {
      return;
    }
    const el = ref.current;
    const {top} = el.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
    el.style.top = `${top + border}px`;
  });
  return <div className="block" ref={ref} />;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-mendeleev-7s2zg

Comment: Thanks for answer. But "ensure the parent remains the same between re-renders" is the violation of question requirement for different and independent containers. In chessboard example, dead piece and alive piece containers are too far from each other in the DOM so you won't be able to ensure that.